# How to Empty Input Field After Pressing Enter?

Tags: html, jquery, input, reset

I'm having trouble figuring out how to empty the input field after I press enter. Here is the code I have:

```
$('input').keypress(function(event){
  if(event.which===13){
    // we'll add stuff here
        var todoItem = $(this).val();
        $('ul').append(
        `<li>
        ${todoItem}
        <span>
          <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
         </span>
        </li>
          `);
  }
});
```

Comment: `this.value = ''`

Comment: Or `$(this).val('')`

Comment: Thank you for your input, it definitely reset the text box.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are already familiar with `.val()` which when used without an argument, according to the jQuery documentation (https://api.jquery.com/val/), is used to "get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements." You can, however, also use the same method with a `value` argument to "set the value of each element in the set of matched elements." By setting the value to an empty string like so: `.val('')` you can clear the input field when needed.

Comment: Hi Ian, thank you for your input. It definitely reset the text box. Now I need to figure out why the text submitted changes to [object Object]. At least now I'm on the right path. Thanks again!